# How to get info why new activity doesn't want to start?

Tags: android, android-activity

Simple:

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:"+_lat+","+_lon);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

`startActivity()` crashes my app (I know why). So, I want to get info why this activity doesn't want to start and (maybe) show some info via toast, via `showToast(msg)`.

PS: I am beginner. :)

Comment: Can you have a look at logcat and post the trace please ?

Comment: look at the `logcat` and you can get the info

Comment: @Krylovech: post your logcat here.....

Comment: @DamienDub so, and can I show some info via toast? PS: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:, }

Comment: @Krylovech You need to handle the exception thrown by startActivity(). In the catch block you can show a Toast message with the exception's message although it's probably bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it crashes then there is an exception. Surround your `startActivity()` call with `try` `catch` and catch the exception. The exception will give you all info you need. You can also show `toast` from the catch block.

Comment: Another problem: Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body. I understand it as startActivity() can't throw anything.

Comment: @Krylovech Use Exception instead of IOException. It will catch everything

Comment: I always remember it, but before I accept answer, I check does it work or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can catch the `RuntimeException` thrown by the `startActivity()` and can write the exception in a `Toast`.

this code may help you.

```
try{
    //your code
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:"+_lat+","+_lon);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
} catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(context, e.getmessage(), duration).show();
}
```